# How to make a cloud mask from a daily MOD09 image?

Tags: remote-sensing, modis

I'm currently working with MODIS data and i've been having some trouble with several aspects of the steps I need to take.

For example, I need to make a cloud mask from a daily MOD09GQK image, and i'm confused on how to do it. I have the QC_250m layer in a tif, but I don't understand the pixel values. I know I should convert, say 4096 to bits and get: 100000010010110, where the 3rd and 4th bits would represent the 00 'clear' flag.

[image]

But my main doubt is why do I get the same value where the image is cloudy and where the image is clear?

Help, please?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got your email. Sadly I don't have experience creating MODIS cloud masks. I've used the [MOD35 cloud mask data](http://modis-atmos.gsfc.nasa.gov/MOD35_L2/index.html), but I've never done the calculations myself.

That being said, I believe that MOD09 reflectance data are already corrected for cloudcover. There is a 2-bit word in the MOD09 QA layer for "Cloud state" that can be either Clear, Cloudy, Mixed, or Unknown. If your task is just to read these bits, then let me know and I can help you with that.

If you truly have to create your own cloud mask from scratch, you may have to use lower-level radiance data (MOD02).

Comment: Thank you! My task is just to read those bits... I have the QC_250m layer in a tif, but I don't understand the pixel values. I know I should convert, say 4096 to bits and get: 100000010010110, where the 3rd and 4th bits would represent the 00 'clear' flag. But this appears where I'm seeing clouds...

Comment: Try http://acc6.its.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~gurwitz/core5/nav2tool.html as decimal to bitpattern converter. You will find the QA bit patterns explained in http://modis-atmos.gsfc.nasa.gov/reference_atbd.html --> Cloud Mask --> PDF, see pp. 14+15.

Comment: @vascobnunes The MODIS data QA layers use big-endian reference, which means the "first" bit is the farthest to the right and the "last" bit is the farthest to the left. So bits 3 and 4 from 100000010010110 are (in bold) 10000001001 **01** 10. Although bits are numbered right to left, bit words are still read left to right, so you would *not* reverse "01" to "10". The meaning of "01" is cloudy. The LPDAAC recently published [this useful guide](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/content/download/19956/71571/version/2/file/MODIS_LP_QA_Tutorial-1.pdf) about how to use MODIS QA bands.

Comment: That's a very important info I didn't know of - I studied earth sciences not computer science, though I enjoy it a lot :) related to the QA layer, I still have some doubts because, I get the same value where the image is cloudy and where the image is clear...

Comment: @vascobnunes I figured it out! According to the [MOD09 QA website](http://landweb.nascom.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/QA_WWW/displayCase.cgi?esdt=MOD09&caseNum=CC_MOD09_09030&caseLocation=cases_data&action=big&test=) "The cloud flags in MOD09Q1 are deliberately not populated. Users are directed to use the data state flag from MOD09A1 in to obtain a cloud mask for use with MOD09Q1 data." You're using a slightly different product, but it looks like this still applies. Try using the MOD09GA product to get the cloud mask.

Comment: @dmahr with the MOD09GA I still have the problem of not having 250m resolution.

Comment: @vascobnunes Page 34 of the [MOD09 user guide](http://modis-sr.ltdri.org/products/MOD09_UserGuide_v1_3.pdf) says "All cloud information should be derived from State QA SDSs...bits labeled as "cloud state" are to be ignored: they have not been populated since Collection 3." I think your best bet is to use the state QA band in MOD09GA and resample it to your desired spatial resolution. The MOD09GA webpage on LPDAAC says "Note that all bit flags in this SDS can be applied to the respective 500m and 250m reflectance data."